# How to read/copy text from SAP shell container using vba?

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

Here is the problem. I need to get the text from an SAP pop up window (image below) using VBA.[image]

I am using watches to view the shell container:
[image]

What I need is to read Text (see the green arrows). So far, my code manages to navigate all the way to the Change Request Comments pop up window but when I use:

```
ntxt=ssn.findById("wnd[1]/usr/cntlCHGTEXT/shellcont/shell").Text
```

to get the text, I get a blank variable. ntxt is a string variable. Please, I need your help. Thanks.

Comment: That's not the proper object, scroll up in your shell container to get the exact name, then do `ntxt = someShell.Text`

Comment: Thanks, @pgSystemTester. I think I may have found the actual name of the shell container and procede with your suggestion.